# Swift - List from JSON only appearing upon view recall

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a section of my application that is built from a call to an external API, which returns a JSON object which I then display through a list in my application. The code for this can be seen below, the requesting function as well as the actual SwiftUI display of the data.

```
struct ImportantBrokenView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = Fetcher()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var user: UserFetcher
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { metrics in
                if (self.fetcher.hasFinished == true) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack(alignment: .top){
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            NavigationView {
                                VStack(alignment:.center) {
                                    Text("JSON List").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.bold).padding(.bottom, 0).padding(.top, 10)
                                    Divider()
                                    Spacer()
                                    List{
                                        ForEach(self.fetcher.fetched ?? []) { result in
                                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                                        Text(result.name).font(.system(size: 26)).fontWeight(.semibold).padding([.horizontal, .top])
                                                      
                                                    
                                                    }
                                            }.listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                                        }
                                    }.frame(width: metrics.size.width * 1.0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
                } else {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Text("Loading...")
                        }.frame(width: metrics.size.width * 1.0)
                    }.frame(width: metrics.size.width * 1.0, height: metrics.size.height * 1.0)
                }
            }.onAppear { self.fetcher.request(authToken: self.user.user!.accessToken) }
        }
    }
}

public struct Model2: Codable, Identifiable {
    public let id: Int
    public let name: String
}

public struct Model: Codable {
    public let fetched: Model2
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fetched = "return"
    }
}

public class Fetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fetched: Model?
    public let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Fetcher,Never>()
        
        @Published var hasFinished: Bool = false {
            didSet {
                objectWillChange.send(self)
            }
        }
        
        func request(authToken: String) {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/api/getdata") else { return }
            
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            
            let APIauthToken = "Bearer " + authToken
            urlRequest.addValue(APIauthToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                
                do {
                    if let d = data {
                        let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: d)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
                            guard let _weakSelf = self else {return}
                            _weakSelf.fetched = decodedLists
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No Data")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }.resume()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
                guard let _weakSelf = self else {return}
                _weakSelf.hasFinished = true
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, which is fairly inclusive of all of the code which generates the JSON which is used to derive the Swift list. When I run this, my list is blank. When I go back in the navigation stack, and then re-enter the view, the list is occupied. Why?

If I had to throw out a guess, I would say it has something to do with the deadline included in the DispatchQueue additions being the same for both the request and the hasFinished response.

Comment: Unrelated but the `weak self -> strong self` dance is nonsense. `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles. `dataTask` works asynchronously, the completion handler is performed later. Rather than the weird `asyncAfter` expressions call `objectWillChange.send(self)` in the completion handler.